# How to write test cases for mapDispatchToProps in Jest and Enzyme using React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

How can I write the testcases using [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(framework)) and [Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) for the given code below?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getTicketTypes: (request) => dispatch(ticketTypeActions.processTicketTypeRequest(request))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it’s connected to a [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library))(-like) state management. I would treat is a black box and would focus on triggering the `mapDispatchToProps` function in a (dummy) component and checking how the application reacts to it.

I would just follow the best practices in *[Writing Tests](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests)*.

If that’s too vague or difficult: `dispatch` is received as a function argument, and therefore you can create a mock of `dispatch` and create expectations based on how `request` is passed to the mock.